# How to integrate existing angular js application into Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have one already developed Angular js application.Routing and templates are already done in that application.

Now my customer need it to integrate this application using Laravel for PHP integration.

Guys please guide me how I proceed.

If we can't able to integrate then kindly suggest any other PHP framework which is comfort for angular application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS is javascript, it runs on user's browser, Laravel is php, it runs on your server. They communicate via HTTP requests and they are complelty independant one from another.

If you have to migrate your application from AngularJS to PHP, that means you have to write your application again, because they have different logic, approaches and way of working.

If you have to let your AngularJS communicate with a remote server, that is done via ajax requests and it doesn't matter what framework you use, since AngularJS will only look at the output produced from your server.